# GoogleAPI refusing apps Artifact upgrade problem

Tags: android, google-api

Until a few days ago i was able to upload new versions of my apps to the app store through the googleAPI with no problem but now I am getting the following error (with no code changes)

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
  {
    "code" : 403,
    "errors" : [ {
      "domain" : "androidpublisher",
      "message" : "Artifact upgrade problem with 97.",
      "reason" : "apkUpgrade"
    } ],
    "message" : "Artifact upgrade problem with 97."
  }
```

My app version is not 97, its 66 I have no idea where that number came from.  The current app version in the store is below 66.   I cannot find anything like this problem on the web

Edit: I forgot to mention that if i manually upload the APK it works fine

Comment: This is happening to me with Fatlane Supply, when I use Gitlab CI to deploy. Doesn't happen when I try it locally, it uploads fine. Don't know why, and there's no detail in the response to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem, so I took the APK manually to the Play Store, and was greeted with the following:

> Warnings Your app currently targets API level 22 and must target at
>   least API level 26 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized
>   for security and performance.

I updated my targetSdkVersion to 26, then all was right with the world.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense so if you have a warning then fastlane doesnt work properly?